# Parse this JSON file to put the values into rows and columns

Tags: arrays, json, sql-server

I have a JSON file that is generated and uploaded nightly into SQL Server as a single entry (This is the code used and an image of the entry)

```
INSERT INTO DTReport.JSON_TEST (DATE, [log])
Select  getdate(),BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'c:\BROWSER.JSON', SINGLE_CLOB) as j
```

[image]

What I want to do is parse the data and create a separate row (and time stamp it) for each entry

So the table would be simply

```
Col1        Col2                 Col3
(Date)      (Browser Version)   (COUNT)
11/2/2019    IE7                 620
11/2/2019    IE11                599
etc....
```

Here is the content of the browser.json file.
I have tried reading about the OPENJSON function but I am unclear how to loop through the information stored in that single entry and then put it into rows and columns

```
FILE CONTENTS
BROWSER.JSON
{"extrapolationLevel":1,"columnNames":["top(browserMajorVersion,10)","count(*)"],"values":[["IE 7",620],["IE 11",559],["Chrome 78",477],["Chrome 77",406],["Firefox 69",152],["Edge 18",79],["Chrome Mobile 78",75],["Firefox 70",74],["Safari mobile 13",48],["Chrome 76",43]]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the next example as one possible approach. The `values` object is a `JSON` array, so you need an additional `APPLY` operator using second `OPENJSON()` call:

JSON data:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'{
   "extrapolationLevel":1,
   "columnNames":[
      "top(browserMajorVersion,10)",
      "count(*)"
   ],
   "values":[
      [
         "IE 7",
         620
      ],
      [
         "IE 11",
         559
      ],
      [
         "Chrome 78",
         477
      ],
      [
         "Chrome 77",
         406
      ],
      [
         "Firefox 69",
         152
      ],
      [
         "Edge 18",
         79
      ],
      [
         "Chrome Mobile 78",
         75
      ],
      [
         "Firefox 70",
         74
      ],
      [
         "Safari mobile 13",
         48
      ],
      [
         "Chrome 76",
         43
      ]
   ]
}'
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE JSON_TEST (DATE date, [log] nvarchar(max))
INSERT INTO JSON_TEST (DATE, [log]) 
VALUES (GETDATE(), @json)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT t.[DATE], j.*
FROM JSON_TEST t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.log, '$.values') WITH (
   BrowserVersion varchar(50) '$[0]',
   [Count] int '$[1]'
) j
```

Result:

```
DATE        BrowserVersion  Count
03/11/2019  IE 7              620
03/11/2019  IE 11             559
03/11/2019  Chrome 78         477
03/11/2019  Chrome 77         406
03/11/2019  Firefox 69        152
03/11/2019  Edge 18            79
03/11/2019  Chrome Mobile 78   75
03/11/2019  Firefox 70         74
03/11/2019  Safari mobile 13   48
03/11/2019  Chrome 76          43
```

Notes (`JSON` basics):

- When you want to parse `JSON` string and get results as table, use [OPENJSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) table-valued function, with default or explicit schema.
- Function [JSON_QUERY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) extracts an object or an array from a `JSON` string. If the value is not an object or an array, the result is `NULL` in `lax` mode and an error in `strict` mode.
- Function [JSON_VALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) extracts a scalar value from a `JSON` string. If the `path` points to not a scalar value, the result is `NULL` in `lax` mode and an error in `strict` mode

Comment: Zhorov: Thank you for this solution. Your solution is exactly what I was looking for and it provides a very clear example for someone that has been struggling with SQL and now JSON. I always try first myself.. but now i can take this example and adapt it to all other types of arrays i will be dealing with. It is really appreciated you sharing your knowledge!

Comment: @runatyr I'm glad this answer helped.